# Laravel Passport Auth::attempt false, password_verify true

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

I am using passport to signup and login a user using api an guard, but while the signup process works fine I cannot login using my code. I have tested it on another VM where it works fine.

The returned JSON is

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "request": {
        "username": "lloyd.thomas.admin",
        "password": "mypassowrd"
    }
}
```

I have used the native password_verify to test passowrd and it shows it as being valid.
Authcontroller.php

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'remember_me' => 'boolean'
    ]);

    $credentials = request(['username', 'password']);

    if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)){
        return response()->json([
                    'message' => 'Unauthorized',
                    'request' => request(['username', 'password']),
                        ], 401);
    }

    $user = $request->user();

    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;

    if ($request->remember_me){
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    }

    $token->save();
    return response()->json([
                'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
                'token_type' => 'Bearer',
                'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                        $tokenResult->token->expires_at
                )->toDateTimeString()
    ]);
}
```

In App/Models/User

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password) {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }
```

In Routes api.php

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'ApiControllers\AuthController@login');
    Route::post('signup', 'ApiControllers\AuthController@signup');

    Route::group([
      'middleware' => 'auth:api'
    ], function() {
        Route::get('logout', 'ApiControllers\AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user', 'ApiControllers\AuthController@user');
    });
});
```

The username and password passes authentication when using web guard but not api

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: what version of laravel are you using?

Comment: You said the login failed at the top of the question. But you then say it passes authentication when using web guard? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: My apoligies, I should have made the post more clear in saying the api guard was failing although looking at the my code may have been a hint and the fact I am using passport. I will edit the post

Comment: @derek-pollard 5.7.22 The working VM is 5.7.27